# Overriding Windows default hot key using AutoHotkey not working

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to override the Windows default hot key, e.g. to get the Windows program search the default is : `Win`+`s`, I would like to change to `Alt`+`Space`

#### Edited

I tried to work around as below examples, I just still don't understand how to use combination of special keys, I tried to google but still couldn't find the solution

**Working**

- `LAlt::LWin`
- `LAlt::#s`
- `Space::LWin`
- `Space::#s`
- `!Space::MsgBox Hello`

**Not working**

- `!Space::LWin`
- `!Space::#s` (This is the expected solution)

Please guide

Thanks

Comment: AHK is well documented. Have a look at their [docs](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).

Comment: `send #s` works. Sometimes an explicit `send` is needed, this might have been mentioned in the docs, idr.

Comment: Is this Windows 8? Windows 10? What's the command line for it? That's normally better than sending key presses.